# Cookie.txt disabling

Tags: php, curl

ima having a problem with login via curl function......
My problem is that it would like to be able to login without the cookie.txt.......
because if i remove cookie.txt i cant login........ when cookie.txt is there it logins successfully, but i would like to login without using cookies....... i tried unlinking cookie.txt but as i said i cant login then......
PART OF THE CODE

```
$ret=false;
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10";
$data = setData($email,$pass);
$ch = curl_init('https://www.website.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip,deflate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,       1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');


$source=curl_exec($ch);

$info=curl_getinfo($ch);


if($info["redirect_count"]==1)
{
$ret=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't loging without using cookies, neither via curl, nor via browser (unless the site you are logging to implements a different mechanism to save the session id, for example as part of the urls for example, but this is rarely the case and it doesn't depend on you). The reason is that without the cookie the server can't know that the request comes from you and not from someone else.

Comment: So No Solution for my problem :3 cause my aim is i would like to be able to try more than 3 times my pass t....... i wonder if there is a way evry try cookies gets renewed or maybe delted

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't implement a login system that doesn't use cookies, so you can't.

Comment: I was able to do it in python i mean loggin without any cookies or anth, so i think in php it can be achieved too

Comment: @MADMIKE — That seems unlikely. I suspect that you are just using a Python HTTP library that handles the cookies more transparently than cURL.

Comment: Yes your totally right but doing the job...... but as you know php as much faster than python thats y i prefer to do it on php too :3 but untill now nth......